# Removing "TooLongFrameException" restrictions (http)

Tags: selenium, http, netty, browsermob-proxy

I am using selenium with browsermob-proxy, ultimately powered by "netty-all", to access a site (outside my control) which offers up enormous headers as part of its authentication process. Proxy fails with a netty error:

`io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than 16384 bytes., version: HTTP/1.1`

I need to remove all such limits from `netty-all`jar that my browsermob-proxy depends on, scalability, performance and memory conservation are not relevant in this use case.

Having cloned the repo, I changed:

- `DEFAULT_MAX_FRAME_SIZE` in `WebSocket00FrameDecoder` (io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx)
- `HttpObjectDecoder` default constructor in `io.netty.handler.codec.http`

to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` where appropriate.

However, even with these new settings it keeps throwing out "HTTP header is larger than 16384 bytes" in use.

1. Where else could this 16384 limit be coming from?
2. How does one remove it while retaining full functionality (at the acceptable cost to efficiency/memory usage etc)

Comment: please add the full stracktrace

Answer (score 0):

Arrived at solution, its far from elegant but it works - my use case is inefficiency/fault tolerant so use with care.

1. I wont pollute this answer with Maven shenanigans as they are not strictly relevant, however, please note that `netty-all` by default pulls all of its components from the Maven repo. To change `netty-all` internals you will need to produce a jar of a required component (`handler.codec.http` in this case), then change `pom.xml` to pull in your modified jar. There are several methods to do this, the only one that worked for me was using `mvn install` to place the jar in the local .m2 repo:

   `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=netty-codec-http-4.1.25.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=io.netty -DartifactId=netty-codec-http -Dversion=4.1.25.Final-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar`

   Then build `netty-all` to get the final jar, which you then use in your own project instead of the original.
2. Files modified to remove size limits from http operation:

   - all/pom.xml
   - codec-http/pom.xml
   - codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpObjectDecoder.java
   - codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocket00FrameDecoder.java
   - codec-http/src/test/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpRequestDecoderTest.java
   - codec-http/src/test/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpResponseDecoderTest.java
3. Aside from setting various size restrictions to Integer.MAX_VALUE, I commented out relevant tests to ensure that Maven "package" command succeeds in producing the jar.
4. The `git diff` of the changes is available here:

   https://gist.github.com/granite-zero/723fa55ae628494ff9b833dde1973a00

   You could apply it as a patch to netty commit 04fac00c8c98ed26c5a75887c8e7e53b1e1b68d0